# Have EF Core 5 introduced new QueryRootExpression concept?

Tags: c#, ef-core-5.0

When merging to EF Core 5 my queries stopped working and while investigating I noticed that the underlying expression return type have changed. I used to get an expression return type like such :

```cs
{value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[TContext.TEntity])
```

Now I'm getting :

```cs
{[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryRootExpression]
```

and it breaks my queries with

> System.ArgumentException: must be reducible node
> at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ReduceAndCheck()

Is this a real change or am I missing something?

Comment: Best to ask on their GitHub.

Comment: Yes, the EF Core team have modified lots of the internal workings of the query compiler. I'd recommend posting the query and the full stack trace to a github issue.

Comment: Yes, they changed the representation of `DbSet` in query expression tree. But that shouldn't cause issues with their own code. Most likely you are using some 3rd party expression processing library which has issues with custom expressions - LINQKit fro instance?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted to their github. @IvanStoev Good info, but no 3rd party library, I've built my own expression however

Comment: @GustavNilsson I see. Before EFC5.0, the `DbSet<T>` instances were contained in `ConstantExpression.Value`, now they are represented with `QueryRootExpression` with information about `IEntityType`. query provider and queryable type, bit no actual `IQueryable` instance.

Comment: @GustavNilsson Would it be possible for you to update this to include a LINQ query that used to work, but now doesn't? I'm running into a similar issue, and wouldn't mind starting a bounty on your question, if it had a bit more detail.